# ffmpeg, how to create two output files while capturing?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a screen recording project that's successfully capturing the desktop video and audio into an MP4, via the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -report -y -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 5 -thread_queue_size 3000 -i :44
    -f alsa -ac 1 -thread_queue_size 3000 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -c:v libx264
    -preset veryfast -crf 28 -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac
    -strict -2 video_and_audio_output.mp4
```

That works fine. What I want is to simultaneously create an additional output that contains just the audio track, without having to make a second pass at the file. Is this possible? And if so, any leads on how to set up the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 5 -thread_queue_size 3000
    -i :44 -f alsa -channels 1 -thread_queue_size 3000 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -map 0
    -map 1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 28 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -f tee
    "[select=v,a:movflags=+faststart]video_and_audio_output.mp4|[select=a:movflags=+faststart]audio.m4a"
```

- For [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab) use `-video_size` instead of `-s` and `-framerate` instead of `-r`.
- For [alsa](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#alsa) use `-channels` instead of `-ac`.
- Only outdated versions need `-strict -2` (or `-strict experimental`) to encode with `-c:a aac`.